# is google chrome api a rest api?

Tags: javascript

Hey guys i have been wondering about the api structure of Google.

I have been working with `google chrome, and I dont understand the api structure. I have heard of rest apis..But rest api is something which is http based and the result must be in the form of a json array.

But in the case of google chrome api the result is not returning as a json format and is not an `http based system` actually.

Could anyone tell me how was the google chrome api  was made actualy ??..Is it rest with architecture ???..or any other architecture.

Please help me if anyone has any idea regarding this ??..Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The Chrome API is not a REST API.

In fact the Chrome API is not a Web API at all. You can think of it more as a Javascript library.

Here you can find the [wiki for WebApis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API) and here is the [Mozilla wiki for WebApis](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI).
Long story short a Web API is called from a client to a server (has both client and server side) whereas your Chrome API just has a bunch of functions/methods to facilitate what you do.

Answer (score 1):

REST is a way to structure APIs that are exposed over HTTP.

The Chrome API is just a set of Javascript functions.

Answer (score 0):

A REST API is not *necessarily* HTTP based. It just so happens that HTTP satisfies REST constraints like presenting a uniform interface to entities, unique identification of entities, and conveying semantic information about representations via media-types.

The Chrome API is simply an API that exposes a set of functions, and so it has nothing to do with REST. If the API is somehow exposed over HTTP, then it would be possible to provide a RESTful facade over the existing API.